# curl SSL certificate error

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to install Vaprobash via CURL but I get this message everytime I try to download something through CURL. I'm using a Mac.

```
curl -L http://bit.ly/vaprobash > Vagrantfile
```

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
>        More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
>         of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
>         bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>         using the --cacert option.
>        If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
>         the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
>         problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
>              not match the domain name in the URL).
>        If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
>         the -k (or --insecure) option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append option in curl call:

```
-k/--insecure
```

The curl will be not trying to verify SSL cert.

Answer (score 1):

The link is redirecting to a secure HTTP (SSL) server, and curl doesn't have access to the proper chain of trusted certificates to confirm that the site says it is who it is.

If you're sure the site is legitimate, and this is a once-off effort, you can use the --insecure option (it will ignore any certificate errors).  Opening the link in a browser directs to GitHub with no issues, and curl fetches it fine on my Ubuntu 12.04 box.

It's likely a missing certificate in your SSL installation.  Run with the `-v` option to get a detailed output if you need to confirm this.

Comment: but what if its not a once off effort? this question has accepted an answer that isn't the answer. making it difficult for future people to ask this question and try to get an answer to it.