# curl error: 60 Seller Center SDK

Tags: php, curl, sdk, guzzle

i'm having a problem using Seller Center SDK from this site:

https://github.com/rocket-internet-berlin/SellerCenterSDK-PHP

i did exactly like what he told. and when i came to the point to test it

```
php ./genericGetter.php
```

i got error saying:

```
curl error 60: ssl certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

i tried to turn off my firewall and added `cacert.pem` from this site https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem to my `php.ini` and still no luck. can someone provide a solution?

Comment: Please try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228226/curl-ssl-certificate-error

Answer (score 0):

You can try add it to php.ini

```
curl.cainfo=c:\path\to\cacert.pem
```

And try set opt_option if still not work.

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
```

Answer (score 0):

just figured it out.

inside `vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\HandlerCurlFactory.php`, on `line 329`; change;

```
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = true;
```

to

```
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
```

so far, i don't know the side effect that might happens. but, it does work fine now.

hopefully this is useful for those who wants to work with Seller Center SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust the source that you are consuming the resources from then arguably I would say that you can deactivate that option temporally as you already did but I would recommend you to check the root of the issue for a long-term solution.

It seems that the issue is with curl not having a valid certificate:

- Check if your server has the latest cacert.pem file which you can download from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and add to the server certs directory.
- if the server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in cacert then it might be expired, or the name might not match the domain name your SDK is using.

If you still not having a solution then check the link below to see if one of the options provided can give you a solution:
[curl: (60) SSL certificate : unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)